# Can't initialize vector C++

Tags: c++

SockeClient.h file

```
#define SIZE_OF_BUFFER 4096

class SocketClient {

public:
    SocketClient(int cfd);
    virtual ~SocketClient();

    int recv();
    int getFd();

protected:
    int             m_fd;
    char            *m_buffer;
    vector<char>    m_vbuffer;

};
```

I was trying to do

```
vector<char>    m_vbuffer(SIZE_OF_BUFFER);
```

And I got a syntax error... How do I initialize the vector with size of 4096.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error you got and where did you try to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use member-initialization-list, in the constructor's definition as:

```
class SocketClient {

public:
    SocketClient(int cfd) : m_vbuffer(SIZE_OF_BUFFER) 
    {                   //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ member-initialization-list

         //other code... 
    }


protected:
    int             m_fd;
    char            *m_buffer;
    vector<char>    m_vbuffer;

};
```

---

You can use member-initialization-list to initialize many members as:

```
class A
{
  std::string s;
  int a;
  int *p;
  A(int x) : s("somestring"), a(x), p(new int[100])
  {
    //other code if any
  }
 ~A()
  {
     delete []p; //must deallocate the memory!
  }
};
```

Comment: @DumbCoder - `reserve` is not enough if you use the vector as a buffer. It needs to have a `size()` and not just a `capacity()`.

Answer (score 1):

Call m_vbuffer->reserve(SIZE_OF_BUFFER) in the constructor of SocketClient.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers consider using some [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) instead of vector. There is one in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html).

Comment: That would be overkill for allocating space for a vector with char elements.